# Autocomplete is not working: DBeaver plugin in Eclipse for Oracle PL/SQL in MacOS

Tags: oracle, eclipse, autocomplete, dbeaver

**Autocomplete** is not working for **DBeaver** plugin (21.1.0) in Eclipse (2021-03) for Oracle PL/SQL (Oracle DB Developer VM: Oracle 19.3) in MacOS (Catalina).

It **does** autocomplete for SQL queries with MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Oracle.

But, with Oracle PL/SQL, it **does** *some* case changes and syntax highlights, but **NO code completion**.

For example, if I start typing DECLARE or BEGIN, it does NOT prompt it. But, once I complete these keywords, they are automatically turned to upper case and changes color to blue.

However, when I type `dbms_output.put_line` it **neither** prompts anything **nor** changes case **or** color thereafter.

(***Noticed**: In Oracle SQL Developer, it prompts several options as we continue typing the above command, and also does syntax highlight thereafter. Similarly, it prompts options, and code snippets with initial 3 letters like `dec`, etc.*)

By default, the following are **checked**:

Windows > Preferences > Database > Database Editors > SQL Editor > Code Complete >

```
Enable auto activation
Activate on typing
Auto-insert proposal
```

Any idea?

Comment: This question doesn't work for me by just saying that autocomplete is not working instead of giving an exact step-by-step instruction how to reproduce this issue with the actual result vs. the expected result. Please improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @howlger Thank you very much howlger for your help. Appreciate, if you please see the details added.

Comment: @tom_kp  I've noticed the same issue, did you get any solution? or you can send/open a ticket (new issue) to DBeaver team through their web site?